# Why does my French Schengen visa say Marsault, or Goat in English?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, embassies

Bonjour, travelers. 
I received a Schengen visa from the French embassy in my country. It was a tourist visa and was my first time to receive a Schengen visa.

It looks like this:

[image]

I had to go to the French embassy because I was trying to get the visa to attend an event in Spain. This explains the "R/ES" remark, but please take a look at the pink arrow.

It says "Marsault", and it is not a part of my name. From what I can see, "Marsault" in French translates to "Goat" in English. The biometric information paper (the one they issue after taking your fingerprints and the photo) does not mention the word "Marsault" either.

I'm just noticing this right now, and I had no problems using this visa. If they put "Pig" or "Elephant", I can figure out it was about my overweight body, but "Marsault" or "Goat" is a little bit confusing.

Is it normal for Schengen visas to carry some sort of unique identification, or some valid clue about my physical appearance or the purpose of visit?

Comment: Do you have a goatee?

Comment: Marsault certainly does not mean goat, it's a type of tree and it could be someone's last name too, presumably some visa officer

Comment: It is the decision-maker's surname.

Comment: Sir Gayot, why are you not adding that as an answer... ;)

Comment: If you had looked at the signature, you could have got your answer immediately.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't realized that it is his name printed there. I have never seen the visa officers name printed on the visa itself, so it didn't come to my mind. Apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: I suggest you use opaque black rectangles instead of blurring to hide text in personal documents. Blurred text can be [surprisingly easy to recover](https://dheera.net/projects/blur).

Comment: Google Translate has been fooled by a coincidence into thinking that "marsault" means "goat". It is in fact a kind of willow tree, also called "saule marsault" (where "saule" means willow). Its common name in English is "goat willow". "Marsault" doesn't derive from goat at all, but when statistical machine translation software sees "goat willow" used to translate "saule marsault", and "willow" used to translate "saule", it infers (wrongly) that "marsault" can be translated as "goat".

Comment: Downvoters, seriously! it is an honest question with some humor.. +1 from me @AyeshK

Comment: For the record, the French word for goat is "chevre".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Neat, I didn't know that - I knew that "chevre" was an English word for goat cheese, but I didn't know that was because it literally just meant "goat" in French. Interesting.

Comment: @CGCampbell I wouldn't add an answer; it's available to a rep hungry noob (which we need more of by the way).  "Marsault" in this case is related to a saint. In any case the UK stopped identifying ECO's because their activities are invidious.  So now they use numbers and initials :)

Comment: @isanae: yes, blurred text may be even easier than the method you cited: http://smartdeblur.net

Comment: Did you honestly believe that visa officials would insert (potentially highly insulting) names of animals such as pig for someone overweight?

Comment: How *did* you get them to accept a picture with that little detail in it?

Comment: No [freehand red circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/216712)?

Comment: This is the name of the person who signed the visa. I have 7 visa from French ambassy  and on each visa I have different names. 2 of thoses names are visible on signature. :)))))
And Marsault also is visible on the signature.

Comment: I don't see it clarified in your answer, are you a goat? I mean, this is 2016, I won't judge.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is simply the name of the officer. The signature on the visa matches this name.

Furtheron, as @hobbs remarked, his name accidentially means "Goat Willow", which is a certain kind of tree. In fact, Saule des Chèvres is another French name for this tree, which literally translates to "Goat Willow". See [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saule_marsault).

However, this is pretty common in France to have names that are common names from the daily vocabulary.

Comment: My recent one says E-VID***TI &signatures on it. So it is indeed the name or identifier of Visa Officer. My earlier one on Nov-2014 had nothing, but two ones on 2015 has one.